# ASP.NET Core Middleware MVC/React MapSpaFallbackRoute

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-mvc, middleware

I try to setup a .NET Core WebApplication that uses SPA to serve the React part of the application and MVC for my Admin-area.

The React app is available at "/"
The MVC part should be available at "/admin"

I have setup my middleware as follows:

```
// Standard routing
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "admin/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        // Fallback Route for /admin and /api
        app.MapWhen(x => x.Request.Path.Value.ToLower().StartsWith("/admin") || x.Request.Path.Value.ToLower().StartsWith("/api"), builder =>
        {
            builder.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallback",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });
        });

        // use SPA for other requests
        app.MapWhen(x => !(x.Request.Path.Value.ToLower().StartsWith("/admin") || x.Request.Path.Value.ToLower().StartsWith("/api")), builder =>
        {
            builder.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        });
```

This works as intended in development mode on my machine (using the ReactDevelopmentServer).

When I make a release and publish it, all requests are routed to the React (SPA) application, thus making my /admin MVC part inaccessible.

What is wrong with my setup? I would appreciate any hint.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Oh my god!

I found the problem. It is related to the Boilerplate React Code created by Visual Studio: it uses a file called registerServiceWorker.js which is pure evil! It uses a damned sticky browser cache which renders everything almost static.

The .net part of the Visual Studio template is correct you can just use the standard middleware setup and all non Spa request will be routed as expected:

```
// Standard routing
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "admin/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Actually, the `registerServiceWorker.js` is not that evil. See [making-a-progressive-web-app](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app) . By the way, the so-called "evil" `registerServiceWorker.js` is not created by Visual Studio, it is created by [`create-react-app`](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/).